# c# считывание ошибки в запущенном процессе

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, процесс

Есть форма содержащая код, который запускается обычной кнопкой.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\program.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -test";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        string stderr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(stderr.ToString());
```

Проблема в том, что если опциях процесса стоит

```
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

То форма как-бы зависает, к примеру нельзя нажать на вторую кнопку, если она есть.

```
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
```

При запуске появляется окно, как только, я его закрываю, срабатывает MessageBox который выводит ошибку (т.е всё работает).

Я так понимаю, когда стоит :

```
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

В невидемом режиме висит окно, которое никто не может закрыть и по этому не срабатывает вывод ошибки в MessageBox ?

Comment: Запущенное приложение не завершается, в нем проблема. Поэтому `WaitForExit` ждет закрытия окна либо завершения приложения. Если бы приложение само завершалось, все бы работало как надо. То есть проблема не в этом коде, а в коде другого приложения.

Comment: Данные ошибки как я понимаю всё равно считываются, только не могут отобразиться так как приложение "висит". Тогда можно его как-то закрыть, чтобы данные поступили в MessageBox ?

Comment: А чтобы приложение само завершалось, не сделать? Почему вызываемый процесс зависает? Это ваше приложение, или что? Я же вам написал, что исправлять, а вы как-будто не услышали. Что у вас там в коде процесса? `ReadLine` или `ReadKey`? Что за тип приложения?

Comment: Все верно вы написали - только вот приложение не моё.

Comment: Ну тогда надо больше кода видеть, например метод полностью, ждать до какого-то таймаута асинхронно. Тип приложения вашего узнать и версию .NET. Пока вопросов больше, чем ответов. Отредактируйте вопрос, укажите больше информации и кода, добавьте в метки тип приложения.

Comment: Таймаут не работает, так как окно висит пока его не закроешь.

Comment: Как вам помочь, если вы 1) не поняли, что я написал 2) не ответили ни на один из вопросов и не отреагировали ни на одно предложение. Ваш комментарий про таймаут не в тему. Я знаю решение, но не могу вам его дать, пока не увижу требуемых деталей. Не буду играть в угадайку и телепатию.

Comment: Не нужно играть, я вам чётко обьяснил где проблема, в закрытии приложения. Проблему решил, поставил паузу, а потом убил процесс, в итоге логика получилась так как я и описал и просил помощи её осуществить более лояльным методом. В каком коде процесса ? Весь код я вам изложил здесь. Нет там ReadLine & ReadKey как видите.

Comment: Тип приложения вашего какой? Версия дотнета какая? Код метода целиком покажете? Есть асинхронное решение, но не увидев сигнатуру метода, я не могу её переписать. Что сложного ответить на эти вопросы? Отредактируйте вопрос, укажите больше информации и кода, добавьте в метки тип приложения.

Comment: Создайте форму, повесьте кнопку, выше приведенный код, поместить в функцию, кинуть вызов в кнопку. Вместо моего приложения подставьте cmd.exe с любым аргументом, как будет работать при p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; Я пока что свою проблему решил - вместо p.WaitForExit(); поместил Theard.Sleep(500); после которого "киллю" процесс. Ибо по другому я не знаю как его завершить ибо p.WaitForExit();  не работает как я понял